# ¿Como puedo abrir urls con python?

Tags: python, url

espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un programa que me da valores cada segundo, y quiero abrir url con esos valores,para poder leerlos con modulo wifi, por ejemplo que si tengo una url 192.168.20.10/(valores)
y quiero abrir esa url pero anexando los valores que voy obteniendo es decir:
192.168.20.10/1
192.168.20.10/2
192.168.20.10/3
.
.
.
y asi infitamente, esos valores los voy a leer con un modulo wifi
¿me pueden ayudar con el codigo de envio ?

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente, ayudaría que pusiese más información o partes  de código. De todas formas te dejo mi respuesta, si no es lo que estás buscando, me comentas.

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres es hacer llamadas a una página web, puedes usar el paquete `requests` en python:

```
import requests

#lo almacenamos en una variables para luego poder consultarla
pagina_web = request.get('1 192.168.20.10')

pagina_web.status_code() #nos da la respuesta de la página, 200, 404, etc.

pagina_web.content() #nos da el HTML de la página
```

Esta técnica se llama **Scraping**, se pueden usar varios paquetes para ello:

- request: el que te acabo de mostrar es sencillo y fácil de usar.
- selenium: por si necesitas scrapear páginas que tienen bastante contenido en java
- scrapy: por si necesitas hacer macro proyectos de scraping
- beautifulsoup4: también sencillo de usar, como request, pero es más completo

Comment: Hola, lo que quiero hacer es mandar el orientacion de un carro a un arduino mediante modulo wifi, para hacer que este se mueva.. .tengo entendido que el modulo wifi nos da una direccion como "192.168.0.1/ ", y para enviar las coordenadas  estas se deben anexar a la direccion, asi "192.168.0.1/COORDENADAS" , lo que quiero hacer es que python abra la url con las cordenadas cada segundo por ejemplo si estoy obteniendo estas coordenadas: 10; 20 ;30 ;40 ;50... python deberia abrir la url 192.168.0.1/10.....192.168.0.1/20....192.168.0.1/30.....192.168.0.1/40.....

Comment: en otras palabras lo que quiero es abrir urls pero anexando el dato que quiero enviar, pero que esten en bucle, porque quiero que envie datos constantemente ( y que abra las urls con los datos constantemente )

Comment: Hola Andree, para que sepas esto se llama entregar parámetros por url y puedes leer más al respecto aquí: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string
Ocurre que hay varias formas de pasar paremetros utilizando HTTP, pueden ir en la URL como planteas, pero tambien puedes enviarlos por JSON o XML por darte ejemplos. El tema es que independiente de como sea el medio (y no tienen mucha diferencia para lo que quiereS), tienes que hacer una arquitectura cliente / servidor por HTTP y para eso te recomiendo usar algun framework web como Flask o Django. Pero ya veras que no es del todo simple.

Comment: Ups, lo siento pero no tengo conocimientos sobre ello, había pensado que se trataba de otra cosa. No puedo ayudarte :(